# Oracle Sql Developer

Tags: sql, database-connection, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have this connection string...

```
Data Source=//192.168.43.172:1528/Prod;User Id=erprousq;Password=***
```

Where is my mistake?[image]

Comment: Did you read the part in red?

Comment: Sorry. It's because I use fiction data for screensht

Comment: Minus 1 vote for putting the word port into the screenshot and confusing the issue.  Since you put in the wrong number, ask your dba what the correct one is.

Comment: I get it. Sorry. I understand.

Comment: Are you sure you are not confusing Connection name and Hostname?

Answer (score 0):

You should enter a valid number for Port field, but you have entered a text.

Comment: I put fiction data for screenshot. In fact I used 1528